# C++ Как конвертировать файл в массив "byte array"?

Tags: c++, byte, bytearray

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы брался файл с моего диска (в этом случае .DLL) и байты передавались в "unsigned char binary = "

Пример который должен получиться:

unsigned char binary = {0xBF, 0x48, 0x78, 0x44, 0x20, 0x48, 0x65, 0x78, 0x20, 0x45, 0x64, 0x69,
0x74, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x20, 0x52, 0x45};

Comment: Ну и в чем у вас ошибка? Что не так работает? Где код, который вы написали и он работает с ошибкой?

Comment: Я даже понятие не имею, как это можно реализовать, поэтому и обратился сюда

Comment: Вы умеете открыть файл и прочитать из него один байт?

Comment: Я не умею работать с байтами и информации как это сделать, я не смог найти.

Comment: А какие функции чтения из файла в бинарном режиме вы знаете?

Comment: Правды ради, мне нужно всего лишь взять этот код и забить, это единственная операция с байтами которая мне нужна

Comment: Начнем с того, что `unsigned char binary = {0xBF, 0x48...` работать не будет, надо `unsigned char binary[] = {0xBF, 0x48...`

Comment: Внимательно читаем [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

Comment: Непонятно, вам нужет текст, который вы будете использовать в другой программе, или просто считать файл в память?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте std::ifstream для открытия и чтения файла в бинарном режиме

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {

    std::ifstream file;

    file.open("asd.txt", std::ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    int size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    unsigned char* buff = new unsigned char[size];

    file.read((char*)buff, size);

    file.close();

    //useBuffer

    delete[] buff;

}
```